# VHDL: Signals get U value even though there is another value assigned

Tags: testing, signals, vhdl, xilinx

I’m implementing IDEA algorithm using VHDL, I have a problem in my 
keygenerator module, when I run the simulator I get values U in all of 
the signals even though I assign other values to them.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity keygenerator is
    Port ( round : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           key : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (127 downto 0);
           keyout1 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           keyout2 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           keyout3 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           keyout4 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           keyout5 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           keyout6 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0));
end keygenerator;

architecture Behavioral of keygenerator is

  SIGNAL key0 : std_logic_vector (127 downto 0);
  SIGNAL key1 : std_logic_vector (127 downto 0);
  SIGNAL key2 : std_logic_vector (127 downto 0);
  SIGNAL key3 : std_logic_vector (127 downto 0);
  SIGNAL key4 : std_logic_vector (127 downto 0);
  SIGNAL key5 : std_logic_vector (127 downto 0);
  SIGNAL key6 : std_logic_vector (95 downto 0);

  signal output : std_logic_vector (95 downto 0);


begin

  process (round, key)

  begin
    key0 <= key;
    key1 <= key0(102 downto 0) & key0(127 downto 103);
    key2 <= key1(102 downto 0) & key1(127 downto 103);
    key3 <= key2(102 downto 0) & key2(127 downto 103);
    key4 <= key3(102 downto 0) & key3(127 downto 103);
    key5 <= key4(102 downto 0) & key4(127 downto 103);
    key6 <= key5(102 downto 7); 

    case round is
      when "0000" => output <= key0(127 downto 32);
      when "0001" => output <= key0(31 downto 0) & key1(127 downto 64);
      when "0010" => output <= key1(63 downto 0) & key2(127 downto 96);
      when "0011" => output <= key2(95 downto 0);
      when "0100" => output <= key3(127 downto 32);
      when "0101" => output <= key3(31 downto 0) & key4(127 downto 64);
      when "0110" => output <= key4(63 downto 0) & key5(127 downto 96);
      when "0111" => output <= key5(95 downto 0);
      when "1000" => output <= key6;
      when others => output <= (others => 'X');
    end case;

  end process;

  keyout6 <= output(15 downto 0);
  keyout5 <= output(31 downto 16);
  keyout4 <= output(47 downto 32);
  keyout3 <= output(63 downto 48);
  keyout2 <= output(79 downto 64);
  keyout1 <= output(95 downto 80);

end Behavioral;
```

That's my testbench:

```
-- Description:   
-- 
-- VHDL Test Bench Created by ISE for module: keygenerator
-- 
-- Dependencies:
-- 
-- Revision:
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments:
--
-- Notes: 
-- This testbench has been automatically generated using types std_logic and
-- std_logic_vector for the ports of the unit under test.  Xilinx recommends
-- that these types always be used for the top-level I/O of a design in order
-- to guarantee that the testbench will bind correctly to the post-implementation 
-- simulation model.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY tb_keygenerator IS
END tb_keygenerator;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF tb_keygenerator IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT keygenerator
    PORT(
         round : IN  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         key : IN  std_logic_vector(127 downto 0);
         keyout1 : OUT  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
         keyout2 : OUT  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
         keyout3 : OUT  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
         keyout4 : OUT  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
         keyout5 : OUT  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
         keyout6 : OUT  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal round : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal key : std_logic_vector(127 downto 0) := (others => '0');

   --Outputs
   signal out1 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
   signal out2 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
   signal out3 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
   signal out4 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
   signal out5 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
   signal out6 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
   -- No clocks detected in port list. Replace <clock> below with 
   -- appropriate port name 

   constant I_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

  -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: keygenerator PORT MAP (
          round => round,
          key => key,
          keyout1 => out1,
          keyout2 => out2,
          keyout3 => out3,
          keyout4 => out4,
          keyout5 => out5,
          keyout6 => out6
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   I_process :process
   begin
    key <= X"12345678912345678912345678912345";
    round <="1100";
    wait for I_period/2;
    key <= X"12345678912345678912345678912345";
    round <="1001";
    wait for I_period/2;
   end process;


END;
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that key0 -- key6 should be in the sensitivity list of the process. I'm not sure if that will make a difference.

Comment: Actually, move the assignments to key0,...key6 outside the process (concurrent assignment statements) and add them in place of key to the process sensitivity list. Your remaining code is an output mux with values derived from key0 ... key6. The fellows comment on EESE to your question there is correct about rounds "1001 and "1100" producing 'X's on output.